# Importing gradle projects has encountered a error

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx

So, I've been trying for about 12 hours now importing gradle to m project.

Here's my project setup :

```
C:\MyGame\Workspace\Project
```

Project is my Java Project name.

My libgdx setup thing looks like this :

```
Name : MyGame
Package : com.evh98.project
Game class : MyGame
Destination : C:\MyGame
Android SDK : C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\

libGDX Version : Release 1.6.4
Sub Projects : Desktop, Android, los
Extensions : Freetype, Controllers
Advanced : Eclipse

"Gives me BUILD SUCCESSFUL".
```

I go into eclipse, right click my project name, `>Import...>Gradle>Gradle`

```
Project
Next >
Root Folder : C:\MyGame
Build Model
```

Checks all folders including MyGame
Uncheck "Run After" or i get the "Import Gradle projects has enoucntered a problem. java.lang.NullPoinetException"

Click Finish

Gets : Import Gradle project has enoucntered a problem. Invalid Project Description - error.

I also saw that the MyGame-android gradle project (in my project explorer) has a error.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: does gradle run from the terminal ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I downloaded the gradle setup, and I'm on a windows? :P

Comment: if you do `gradle` from the command prompt, does it work ? I want to know if it's a gradle problem or eclipse

Comment: If you have the Android project generating, do you have the Android SDK and the Eclipse Android dev plugin installed?